# Microsoft Word 2010 - Applying style to selected words

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, styles

I've configured a small number of styles which are working just fine, but I'm wanting to create a new style based on an existing style where the new style can be applied to the selected words, but I can't see anything that could help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to create Character Style instead of Paragraph Style. If you need to inherit it from an existing Paragraph Style, use Linked style type.

Answer (score 1):

im not sure about word 2010 but the word 2011 version on the mac has a 'styles...' under format where you can create a new style by clicking the new button. In the new style dialog there is an option box called  style based on... you can choose from every style that has already been made. hope this was what you were asking.